# Android layout problem when using software keyboard

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

Here is a simplified version of the layout I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
   <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="5dp" android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical" android:isScrollContainer="true">

       <AbsoluteLayout android:layout_width="1000dp" android:layout_height="1000dp" android:background="#ff3344">

           <EditText android:text="test" android:layout_x="50dp" android:layout_y="800dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></EditText>

       </AbsoluteLayout>

   </ScrollView>

   <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top"
             android:gravity="center" android:visibility="visible" android:text="Text View" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The problem is that when the EditText is clicked and the keyboard is shown, the TextView gets pushed upwards out of the screen. I would like the TextView to stay put, and the ScrollView to either pan or resize. I have tried both adjustPan and adjustResize on the activity (either would be ok for the UI's sake). adjustResize WORKS correctly on my Gingerbread device, but not on my Froyo device. adjustPan doesn't work on either one of them.

Comment: For some reason the opening tag of the FrameLayout disappeard, it looks like this: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/top_frame" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="0dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" android:isScrollContainer="false">

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the root layout to `RelativeLayout`, and fix the `TextView` to the bottom. Then let `ScrollView` expand from top to the 'TextView'.

Comment: This works, but gives a somewhat different result.. Perhaps a properly sized container for the text view fixed at the bottom and overlayed on the scroll view would work. I'll have to experiment a bit more with that.